# Color splatter in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, shader, monogame

So I've been searching everywhere for a tutorial on how to create this kind of effect [INK the Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJb7t.jpg)

But I can't seem to find anything helpful, I know I have to use render targets to draw the splatter over my map and some kind of shader to remove the splatter that is not overlapping the map. So if anyone would guide me in the right direction for this it would be really helpful since I'm a total beginner in shaders and render targets.

Comment: a `StencilBuffer` would probably be the easiest way to create that. See https://medium.com/@sfranks/i-originally-wrote-this-for-the-best-way-to-mask-2d-sprites-in-xna-game-development-stack-949cf7bd7421

Comment: @BradleyUffner ahh, that looks way more easy. Thanks alot!

Comment: @BradleyUffner How would i do if i wanted to use scale and a matrix transformation with that example though?

Comment: The basic idea is that you create a render Target for your map area, with a stencil buffer in it, render it as in the example, then draw the texture from the render Target to the display with rotation. I'm sorry a can't help more, but I just left for vacation and don't have access to a computer right now.

Comment: No need for further explanation, i understand the concept. Thanks again :)